# Open specific jquery ui tab based on which the previous page is

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a jquery ui tab and what I would like to do is when the page containing the jquery ui tab loads, specific tab will open depends on the previous page. So far, I have down the following:

PHP:

1. obtain the previous page by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
2. determine which tab to open by using a "if" statement (assigning a tab_index variable);
3. assign "tab_index" to a hidden input value.

Javascript:

1. pick up the hidden input value and assign it to a js variable;
2. ??

Then I am not too sure how to do this make it work in $('#tabs').tabs({.... statement. Any idea of how to resolve this will be much appreciated. Many thanks.

```
PHP:
$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$string = substr($string, -(strlen($string)-strrpos($string, '/')-1), strlen($string)-strrpos($string, '/'));
if ($string == "specific_page.php") {
    $tab_index = 2;
} else {
    $tab_index = 0;
}

HTML:
...
<input id="hidden_input" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tab_index; ?>" />

JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
var tab_index = $('#hidden_input').attr('value')
$('#tabs').tabs({ cache:false,
    ajaxOptions: {
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
        }
    },
    ...something here for tab selection?...
});
});
```

Comment: 3. [PROFIT!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343646/open-specific-jquery-ui-tab-based-on-which-the-previous-page-is)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the active tab by using

```
$(".selector" ).tabs({active: 2 });
```

Meaning, your code would be, if i understand your tab_index correctly.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
cache: false,
active: tab_index,
ajaxOptions: {
    error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
        $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
    }
},
...something here for tab selection?...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Freddy, I will give it a try later today when I have a chance.

Comment: Hi Freddy, after inserted the suggested script, no matter which tab I click, it switches straight back to tab 0. Any idea of how to resolve this? Thank you